# Cos'è "una malamente"?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Lui non si permetterebbe mai di offendere la donna dello zio, la padrona di casa che gli lava le brache e gli cucina i maccheroni. Senza contare le olive e le fette di pane che gli fa trovare sotto il cuscino. Anche se è una **malamente**, non ce l’ha con Lena, e continua a scrivere a casa che si trova bene con la padrona settantenne, e s’è infognato in un pantano di menzogne. Gli dispiace mentire ai cari e amati genitori, ma non ha voglia di andare a Cleveland per colpa di Lena.

Non capisco il significato del termine "malamente" che appare in questo passaggio. Per cominciare, non riesco a vedere se "malamente" è Lena, cioè la donna dello zio, oppure questo "lui" di cui parla il brano, che infatti è un ragazzino chiamato Diamante. Nei dizionari che ho consultato, "malamente" appare soltanto come avverbio e non come nome. Potreste aiutarmi a chiarire i miei dubbi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In dialetto napoletano un/una *[malamente](https://it.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/malamente)* è una persona cattiva, poco raccomandabile.

Nella [sceneggiata napoletana](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sceneggiata) c’è proprio un protagonista così chiamato:

> Ben definiti sono i canoni entro cui le tematiche portate in scena
>   dagli autori delle sceneggiate napoletane, come l'amore, il
>   tradimento, l'onore – talvolta la malavita –, sintetizzate nel
>   trinomio dei protagonisti:
>
> - isso
>     ("lui"), detto anche "tenore", l'eroe positivo;
> - essa
>     ("lei"), detta anche "prima donna di canto", l'eroina;
> - 'o malamente
>     (il cattivo), l'antagonista.

Comment: Quindi, "una malamente" nel testo si riferisce a Lena, no?

Comment: Anche a me sembra così, sicuramente non è riferito a lui